# calculate number of sits in a valid row (combinatorial question)

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve some basic question in computer science although the problem is that I can't figure out how to calculate the combinatorial equation to solve my problem.

Consider a row with with $x$ chairs. in first place (from left to right) should always be a person, next should be maximum 4 empty spaces and then another person and so on. It is possible for the row to have only one place which will be occupied or a place and two, three or four empty spaces and so on. Example for valid rows:

```
p - - - - p - - - - p - -
p - - - - p - 
p - -
p
```

Example of invalid rows:

```
- p - - -
p - - - - -
p - p 
p - - p
p - - - p
```

How can I build an equation to calculate the number of occupied chairs?

**EDIT:**
the following table:

```
total    not-empty chairs
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        1
6        2
7        2
8        2
9        2
10       2
11       3
12       3
```

Comment: There isn't a unique answer.  A row with $4$ chairs could have anywhere from $1$ to $4$ occupied chairs.

Answer (score 1):

It is $\lceil \frac{x}{5} \rceil$ - this means $\frac{x}{5}$ rounded up to the closest integer.

Comment: This would be the minimum number of occupied chairs.  It could be any number from this to $x$.

Comment: Yes, I meant minimum of that.